# Help finding $\lim_{x \to \infty} {(1 + e^x)}^{e^{-x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} {(1 + e^x)}^{e^{-x}}$
Here are the steps I have taken so far : 
$\ln{L} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \ln{({1 + e^x})^{e^{-x}}}\\
\ln{L} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} {e^{-x}} \ln{({1 + e^x)}}\\ 
\ln{L} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} {e^{-x}} \ln{({1 + e^x)}}\\
\ln{L} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\ln{({1 + e^x)}})}{{e^{x}}}\\
\text{Here is where I am not sure how to finish this problem. This is what I tried:}\\
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\ln{({1 + e^x)}})}{{e^{x}}} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}\\
\text{Apply L'Hopitals Rule}\\
\ln{L} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\frac{1}{1+e^x} * e^x)}{e^x}\\
\ln{L} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\frac{1}{1+e^x} * e^x)}{e^x}\\
\ln{L} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \require{cancel} \frac{(\frac{1}{1+e^x} * \cancel e^x)}{\cancel e^x}\\
\ln{L} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+e^x}\\
\ln{L} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+e^\infty} = \frac{1}{\infty} = 0 \\
\ln(0) = \text{Undefined.}$

Help is always appreciated ! also first post on stack exchange mathematics =).

Comment: You are not calculating $ \ \ln 0 \ $ -- you are looking for the number which _has_ a logarithm of zero.  Otherwise your procedure looks all right  (although in your penultimate line, you have already taken the limit, so you just want to write " $ \ \frac{1}{1 \ + \ e^{\infty}} $ " -- I use quotes because that expression is not really a number...).

Comment: If $\ln{L}=0$ then $L=?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only confused yourself at the very last. You have

$$\ln L = 0$$

Taking exponential on both side, you have

$$e^{\ln L} = e^0 = 1,$$

Thus $L = e^{\ln L}  =1$. you should get yourself familiar with this argument. After all, the fact that you can take exponential to convert $\ln L$ to $L$ is the very reason you can take $\ln$ in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, except on the last one when you say $\ln L=0$. This implies that $L=1$, not that $L$ is undefined.

A more well known result is possible.

$e^x=t$.

$$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} {(1 + t)}^{\frac{1}{t}}=1$$

Or, that $$\lim \limits_{x \to o}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure was correct and it's pretty clear that $\log L=0$, so that result doesn't really tell you a whole lot. The way I'd go about doing this isn't very formal, but quite intuitive. So as $x \to \infty$, it's pretty clear that $(1+e^x)$ behaves almost exactly like $e^x$. In other words, $L \sim (e^x)^{e^{-x}}=e^{xe^{-x}}$. Obviously, $xe^{-x} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. So $L \sim 1$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: I am not sure if it is advisable to do so. For example, $(1+\frac 1x)$ also looks like $1$ as $x\to +\infty$, but you cannot calculate the limit of $(1+\frac 1x)^x$ by this argument.

Comment: Well, the orders work out differently. In one case, you have an exponential with a constant being taken to a power and in the other, you have a reciprocal plus a constant being taken to a power.

So that's a yes and a no to answer your question. $(1+e^x)^{e^{-x}}=e^{xe^{-x}}*[1+e^{-x}]^{e^{-x}} \sim e^{xe^(-x)}$ as $x \to \infty$ which leads to the same result. Again, there's a difference between an exponential vs a constant and a constant vs a reciprocal in convergence speeds.

Comment: Yes, so there is an argument involved whenever one tries to use your intuition. Somehow you have to make that explicit in your answer what kinds of argument you need, or it will be a bit misleading.

Comment: It's not misleading at all. It's just basic concepts concerning convergence rates and convergence speeds. It's basic numerical analysis.

Comment: Please, whether or not it is confusing depend on which person you are talking to. Of course it is not confusing to you and me, cause we know (somehow with some additional knowledge) that this method make sense. But for people who is learning this limit stuff, you have to explain clearly why this works.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. Your point is duly noted.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way.

Consider$$A={(1 + e^x)}^{e^{-x}}$$ Take logarithms $$\log(A)=e^{-x}\log(1+e^x)$$ Since $x$ is large $\log(1+e^x)\approx\log(e^x)=x$ So $\log(A)\approx x e^{-x}\to 0$ and then $A\to 1$.

Answer (score 0):

By L'Hospital's Rule, $\displaystyle 0=\lim_{x \to\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^x}=\lim_{x \to\infty}\frac{\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}}{e^x}=\lim_{x \to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+e^x)}{e^x} = \lim_{x \to\infty}\ln((1+e^x)^{e^{-x}}).$
Hence, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to\infty}(1+e^x)^{e^{-x}} = e^0=1.$